# Программное распознание устройства в xCode

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
В своей программе я использую функцию CGRectMake. Для того чтобы корректно разместить элемент на представлении мне нужно знать на каком устройстве оно запущено (iphone, iphone поколение 3.5, iphone поколение 4). Подскажите как это сделать?
И за одно, как узнать версию ios на устройстве?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDevice в помощь.

[UIDevice currentDevice] возвращает объект, который представляет текущее устройство.
А там уже есть куча свойств:

- name
- systemName
- systemVersion
- model
- localizedModel

Comment: Просмотрел класс UIDevice, но так и не понял как распознать retina дисплей. (если iphone 3gs)?

Comment: Взято с просторов StackOverflow:

    BOOL isRetinaDisplay() {
        BOOL isRetina;
    
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
            isRetina = YES;
        } else {
            isRetina = NO;
        }

        return isRetina;
    }

Comment: я немножко не правильно сказал. мне нужно для удлиненного экрана iphone 5 делать одно, а для других экранов iphone другое.

Comment: Эм.. ну CGRectMake принимает в качестве параметров не пиксели, а точки. Поэтому как-то все равно - ретина или нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices. Там ответ с наибольшим количеством голосов. Если хотите, могу завернуть в ответ.

Comment: да нашёл. вот тут тоже очень хорошо написано http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution?lq=1

Comment: Вот поэтому и удивляет, что вы задаёте такой простой вопрос, не выполнив сначала тривиальный поиск на SO.

Comment: Tuggen, если мне скажем нужно добавить элемент через CGRectMake в самый низ, то нужно смотреть не является ли девайс iphone 5, так как у него вытянутый экран и больше точек. на счёт ретины я не правильно выразился

Comment: Ну да, теперь понятно, в чем состоит задача. Я не в курсе, насколько сложен ваш интерфейс, но вместо постоянных проверок можно попробовать поиграть со свойством autoresizingMask для ваших объектов класса UIView.